# CSS: How to give space between backgorund-image and text (with the given properties)?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm learning CSS and I have an assignment where I'm given 12 properties and I need to create this button...

These are the [properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kSm7.png) given to me.

The [button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lo2Hu.png) I need to create.

This is how my [button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cx6gR.png) looks like.

My [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhZU2.png).

I tried everything but I couldn't give a space between the image and the text... help me :(

Comment: Add at the end `padding-left:40px;` or even more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to set here is your `padding-left` and set your `background-position-y` to either 0px or left;

`padding` is a shortcut for `padding-left` , `padding-top`, `padding-right`, `padding-bottom`

You can do your padding as either padding: 15px 15px 15px 50px;
this will make it 15px and padding-left: 50px;

or you can make it

```
padding: 15px;
padding-left: 50px;
```

in this specific order